# Getting axios error "ERR_NETWORK" when fetching data using AWS lambda function url in a react app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, https, axios

I am making a get request in "create react app" as shown below through an AWS lambda function url, but I am getting the error shown in picture below. When I do the same exact request in postman or in web browser I don't get any error. I am allowing cors in my lambda function. Does anyone know the cause of the error?

THE CODE:

```
function searchStock() {
        fetchStock().then(resp=> {
            console.log(resp)
        }).catch(err=> console.log(err))
    }

    async function fetchStock() {
        let res = await axios.get("AWS lambda function url");
        return res;
    }
```

THE ERROR:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should sanity check the function in the AWS dev console to make sure you can invoke it. If that works, I would check the network configuration and/or CORS. Also check the security groups and firewall settings in your AWS account. Ensure that they allow incoming connections from the IP addresses or ranges where your React app is hosted.

Comment: I went to couldwatch app to monitor the lambda function log and it returns the right object as you see in the image link below. I have also set the CORS setting for the function to be accessed from anywhere. I am not sure why the react app is not receiving it. I even tried calling the function in Node.js and it works.

https://i.imgur.com/VhKmWOP.png